# 2 outputs of clock synthesizer connected together

Tags: clock, synthesizer

Can anyone explain what is the purpose of the following schematic?

Why are outputs Y1 and Y3 connected together?

[image: Clock synthesizer]

Comment: I find it kind of unnecessary to explain the purpose of a circuit to you if *you* found the circuit, can't tell us what it's part of and where it's from and what the components are; honestly, while it's OK to ask about the function of a circuit, "hey I found this totally random circuit, and I give zero context, what does it do" is neither sufficiently explained nor researched

Comment: Probably to parallel the drivers for double the current.

Answer (score 2):

Not to state the obvious, but it is to obtain a two frequency clock. This is common in RF, audio, and other applications where two distinct frequencies are required.

Comment: The chip is programmable through I²C. One can select by software whether Y1 or Y3 is on. Changing the divider that way is faster than tuning the PLL to another frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Why not go read the data sheet for the chip. It's programmable so without knowing what instructions have been delivered to it via the digital bus (SDA and SCL) it is impossible to say.

> Why are outputs Y1 and Y3 connected together?

It's feasible that both outputs are set at the same frequency and can thus drive twice the load but that has to be a guess at best.